# How to make a dropdown form work in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a dropdown form in the navigation bar in my Rails application, however, the dropdown form will randomly stop working. Sometimes it works fine, but other times I need to refresh the page to make it work.

I'm using Rails version 6.2.1.

This is my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body id="main-body">
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the dropdown form in the header:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Account <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li
```

I noticed that if I delete

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

the dropdown will work, but it causes other problems. For example, the `DELETE` verb in the routes.rb will raise an error.

Comment: Sounds like a turbolinks issue. This should help: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior

Comment: When you say `it will stop working randomly` are you certain there is no specific action leading up to the error.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no specific action leading up to the error, because I have tried multiple times, comment and uncomment the turbolinks line, and the dropdown just doesn't work randomly when the line is uncommented.

Comment: Randomness doesn't happen in code; SOMETHING is triggering it.

Comment: I understand that it is not supposed to be random, but I just cannot figure out what happens here.

Answer (score 1):

My would be that this occurs when you navigate to the page in question from another another page (not directly putting in the url). With turbolinks enabled JavaScript will handle page loading instead of the browser. Meaning that things like `document.onload` don't get triggered.

One of your plug-ins might attach itself to such an event.

Most JavaScript plug-ins have a handle to manually re-initialize them. In that scenario you should be able to call it when [turbolinks is done loading a page](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior).

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  ThirdPartyLibrary.initialize();
});
```

Alternatively you could drop the turbolinks dependency from your project. This lets pages behave like normal and also should resolve the issue.

Comment: Agree that Turbolinks compatibility sound like the most likely cause. Is the dropdown behavior you are trying to install from Bootstrap? If so, you may want look into Bootstrap compatibility with Turbolinks. 

You can also look into how to disable Turbolinks. (For the record, I really like Turbolinks.)